# Draw line after the paragraph using iText 7 C#

Tags: c#, itext7

How I can draw a line after the paragraph using `iText7` in accessible pdf?

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:accessibility]?

Comment: I'm going to create accessible pdf using iText7. Added paragraph to the pdf and after that I need to draw a line. For that I want to get current Y position. That is the problemm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please go to [chapter 4](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-4-adding-abstractelement-objects-part-1) of the [iText 7: Building Blocks](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/) tutorial, and scroll down to where it says: **Drawing horizontal lines with the LineSeparator object**

You've created a `Document` object to which you are adding `Paragraph` objects, and now you want to add a line. Drawing that line is done with a `LineSeparator` object.

First you need to define a line. You can do this by choosing an implementation of the `ILineDrawer` interface, such as `DashedLine`, `DottedLine`, or `SolidLine`. Let's suppose that you want a solid line with a width of 1 user unit in red. That's done like this:

```
SolidLine line = new SolidLine(1f);
line.setColor(Color.RED);
```

Now that you have a line, you can use this to create a `LineSeparator` object:

```
LineSeparator ls = new LineSeparator(line);
```

You can define different parameters, such as the width percentage:

```
ls.setWidthPercent(50);
```

The above line will draw a line that takes only 50% of the available width.

You can also define some margins:

```
ls.setMarginTop(5);
```

The above line will make sure there's 5 user units of free space above the solid lines.

Please consult the tutorial and the [API documentation](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText7/latest/) to find out which other parameters you can set.

I'm not sure why your question was downvoted, but as you can see, you were asking for something you didn't need. You wanted to draw a line under a `Paragraph`, but instead of asking how to do this, you asked for the X and the Y position. You don't need to know X and Y to meet the requirement of drawing a line. Hence one could argue that you were asking the wrong question.

Comment: Thanks so much. I edited the question. I tried as below.         
 SolidLine line = new SolidLine(1f);
line.setColor(Color.RED);
LineSeparator ls = new LineSeparator(line);
ls.setWidthPercent(50);
ls.setMarginTop(5);
doc.add(ls);                                                                                                        but  it is not worked. Can you please help me.

Comment: @Briyatis *"but it is not worked."* - this description is not enough to help you.

Comment: When people say "it is not worked", they shouldn't expect any other answer than "but it works for me!" I can't make something work that already works for me. It just works.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Because of the incorrect line width, line was not draw in the pdf. Finally it is worked. Thanks so much.